# How to send an email with HTML tag, not a HTML plain text in C#

Tags: c#, html, email, smtp

I'd like to Send an Email using C#, but sent it with plain HTML text, NOT a HTML tag.

Here's some code below..

```
StringBuilder pl_sbHtml = new StringBuilder();

pl_sbHtml.Append("<html>");
pl_sbHtml.Append("<head>");
pl_sbHtml.Append("</head>");
pl_sbHtml.Append("<body>");
pl_sbHtml.Append("<td>"+ Content Data + "</td>"); // This Content Data is from DB with HTML Tag
pl_sbHtml.Append("</body>");
pl_sbHtml.Append("</html>");

MailAction pl_objMail = new MailAction("Title", pl_sbHtml.ToString(), SmtpHost);

pl_objMail.IsBodyHtml = true;
pl_objMail.AddToMail(TO);
pl_objMail.SetFromMail(FROM);
pl_objMail.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
pl_objMail.SendMail();
```

Current Result in Email :
`< div style='font:30px'> HELLO < /div>` (Can See the HTML Tag.)

**Expected Result in Email :**

HELLO  (applied HTML Tag.)
                            
Thank you !

Comment: Change email body type to html instead of text

Comment: @UK_Dev Ref the code: `pl_objMail.IsBodyHtml = true;`. OP has already done that

Comment: set the format also before adding your html body text, also make sure for sense it has body and html tags

Comment: What is `MailAction`? I can't find reference documentation for it

Comment: it looks like you are setting the plain text body and then saying it should be html but not providing the html body.. have you tried my previous suggestion

Comment: @Martin It is almost same as  MailMessage  Method. just set the title, content, smtp port etc..

Comment: @BugFinder I did about html tags.//  I thought I made a format in  'IsBodyHtml = true;' line.

Comment: @KUNWOOMYUNG Can you add your `MailAction` class?

Comment: @KUNWOOMYUNG well. if its adding that body (as implied by code) before its set to html, no its adding it as raw text.

Comment: @BugFinder I'm pretty sure the order doesn't matter - see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Email content can be really funny and Email Clients vary. I tested this in Outlook

with the original stated content of `< div style='font:30px'> HELLO < /div>`

and it did not render correctly. With a bit of trial and error it seems that the leading spaces in the html tags caused the problem.

Trying

`pl_sbHtml.Append("<td>" + "<div style='font:30px'> HELLO </div>" + "</td>");`

rendered as expected

Re the comments on the OP, it does not matter if you set `IsBodyHtml = true` before or after you set the body, as long as you set it before you send it.

Test Code:

```
StringBuilder pl_sbHtml = new StringBuilder();

var from = "steve@ste-fu.uk";
var to = "steve@ste-fu.uk";

pl_sbHtml.Append("<html>");
pl_sbHtml.Append("<head>");
pl_sbHtml.Append("</head>");
pl_sbHtml.Append("<body>");
pl_sbHtml.Append("<td>" + "<div style='font:30px'> HELLO </div>" + "</td>");
pl_sbHtml.Append("</body>");
pl_sbHtml.Append("</html>");

MailMessage pl_objMail = new MailMessage();

pl_objMail.Body = pl_sbHtml.ToString();
pl_objMail.IsBodyHtml = true;
pl_objMail.Subject = "Testing";
pl_objMail.To.Add(to);
pl_objMail.From = new MailAddress(from);

var client = new SmtpClient("smtp.ste-fu.uk");
client.Send(pl_objMail);
```

Comment: Thanks @ste-fu, But I figured out that the problem is in the other side... But Thank you for your reply!!